1950's Short story about civilization slowly winding backwards
The story I'm looking for was most likely published in an SF magazine the 1950s, but could have been 60s. Very conceptual, it describes a reversing of civilization. No reason is given, just people start moving out of settled areas and giving up technology, running history backwards. I believe it ends with the last English settlers getting on wooden boats to go back to England.

It ends with the main character returning to Egypt, which he thought would last, but eventualy even there things get undone. Steles are uncarved, pyramids unbuilt.

I think this is probably The Man Who Never Grew Young by Fritz Leiber. It was published in 1947 so it fits the time you remember. It has already been asked about a few times, for example in looking for short story / novella - time is flowing in reverse except for the story teller.
The story is told from the perspective of the man who never grows young while he sees  time running backwards around him. His theory it that time started running backwards from some ultimate catastrophe linked to a nuclear war:

I sometimes think (I must hold on to this) that time once flowed in the opposite direction, and that, in revulsion from the ultimate war, it turned back upon itself and began to retrace its former course. That our present lives are only a return and an unwinding. A great retreat.

The part you remember about people boarding their ships is:

But the pressure of the Indians, sporadically aided by foreign allies, increased. City by city, town by town, settlement by settlement, we pulled up our stakes and took ship ourselves across the sea. Toward the end the Indians became strangely pacific, so that the last boatloads seemed to flee not so much in physical fear as in supernatural terror of the green silent forests that had swallowed up their homes.


I identified this story 10 years ago, but this time around I didn't recognize it. :-(

I know this fits the description, but doesn't match my memory at all. I remember a lighter story, very Galaxy/F&SF, and it was told in the third person, almost like a historical account.

@UnknownOrbits Are there any more details you can remember about the story? Anything, no matter how small, might help trigger a memory.
